# get max value of column

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get more value from a column in a table.
My table is very simple:

```
public class MensajeTablon
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int identificadorUsuario { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string mensaje { get; set; }
    public string foto { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public int identificadorTablon { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have 2 rows in my table, with id 1 and one with id 2. When I try to query it returns me an object with id = 0. I do not understand why. My query is:

```
var idMensaje = dbConn.Query<MensajeTablon>("select MAX(id) from MensajeTablon;");
```

I'm sure I have those two rows that if I read the table (select * from MensajeTablon) I get the two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is to create a Class that mirrors the results as well.  So

---

```C#
// the class that represents the result you want
public class MaxId
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

---

```C#
// now you need to cast it to an "id" as well....
var idMensaje = dbConn.Query<MaxId>("select MAX(id) AS id from MensajeTablon");
```

Now `idMensaje[0].id` is your Max

---

[image]

var `existing` is the result of my query

Comment: What about `Query<int>`?

Comment: @CL. hmmm seem it should work.  I will give it a try and see what it returns and update the solution if it does work.

Comment: @CL. It didn't work :(  It return zero in `existing` it should return 30 like the screenshot above.